# Concatenate Two Values On Insert - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax, insert

I'm attempting to accomplish what seems to be something simple, but I'm unable to find a solution - I'm probably wording it incorrectly.

I have a third party software that outputs date and time as two separate values, one for date and the other for time, and I need to be able to `INSERT` that data as one `datetime` field into SQL.

The third party software is built on a proprietary language based on .NET, and using SQL Server 2005.

Here are my two values in the software:

```
let cbdate1 = cbdate
let cbtime1 = cbhr & ":" & cbmn & ":00 " & ampm
```

And then the SQL would go as:

```
DOSQL "INSERT INTO Leads (DateTimeField) VALUES (cbdate1 + ' ' + cbtime1)"
```

So essentially, I am attempting to join the two values upon insert into the table. That does not work, and I'm unable to direct myself to find an appropriate answer.

**Additional Information:**

The Date (cbdate1) is presented as "MM/DD/YYYY" and the Time is simply joined as presented "HH:MM:00 AM"

Comment: What is your database platform, what is the error message, what does the concatenated string `cbdate1 + " " + cbtime1` look like ?

Comment: Use parameterized queries instead of concatenating SQL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are currently using double quotes you should instead use single quotes since that is a valid string in SQL.

```
 DOSQL "INSERT INTO Leads (DateTimeField) VALUES (cbdate1 + ' ' + cbtime1)"
```

**Edit:**

Now if you get further problems it might be because your `DateTimeField` is a `datetime` datatype. Now you could then after concatenating convert or cast the string to the **[correct format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)**.

**Like:**

```
 DOSQL "INSERT INTO Leads (DateTimeField) VALUES (Convert(datetime, cbdate1 + ' ' + cbtime1))"
```

**Edit #2:**

Without a 24 hour part you would need a mon dd yyyy format ex: Oct 22 2012. Otherwise you might have to try and get the time part into a 24 hour format.

Comment: I've edited the statement in the question, it is single quotes in the code I am using.  I simply typed it incorrectly.

Comment: The datatype is datetime, I also did not put that in my original question, lol.  I am batting a 1000 here for errors!

Comment: @RogueSpear00 well I am guessing as long as your string is in a convertable datetime string format that should fix your problem

Comment: Alright - So I took the code into SQL and attempted to replicate to see if the problem with the insert lies within my Proprietary software (the way it formats) or in the way SQL is getting the data and handling it.  When I attempted to pass data into the way you had suggested to convert, I'm getting a "Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string." This isn't bad though, because at least now I know that the SQL is going to work.

Comment: @RogueSpear00 this might also just mean that the format of the string is not a correct one you need to look at some sample valid strings to see if you can tweek the string coming in accordingly. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: Yes I believe it is simply formatted incorrectly, and am looking at how to convert it accordingly.

Comment: @RogueSpear00 check out the 2 links that I posted. In the MSDN article it has a table with a bunch of acceptable formats.

Comment: I have been attempting several variations according to the article, and have yet to find one that succeeds.

Comment: @RogueSpear00 so it looks like without a 24 hour part you would need a mon dd yyyy format ex: Oct 22 2012. Otherwise you might have to try and get the time part into a 24 hour format.

Comment: Alright.  Let me attempt to convert the time portion to 24H and see if that resolves.  Thanks @Laurence!

Answer (score 0):

Join the date and time values together in your source code first, then insert the single value into the database. You don't say what programming language you are using, so I can't tell you how to do that. However, it is simple to do in VB6 and any .NET language.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried.  Unfortunately, for some odd reason anytime I attempt to join the two variables prior to insert, the script throws an error on the join.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is merge the strings together, then cast as a datetime type.  Make sure that the strings are in the proper format. (ie. 01-01-01, 01/01/01, etc.)

```
INSERT INTO LEADS (DateTimeField) VALUES (CAST((cbdate1 + ' ' + cbtime1) as datetime)
```

Refer to the msdn for output formats depending on what you want.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: `01/01/01` is not a very proper format. `'2001-01-01'` or `'20010101'` is.